# Power BI Ignore Rounding in Money values

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

[Round values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdoGC.png)

Why does Power BI (Dax query) always round values?

Example: 12345.678 Power bi rounds to 12345.68

```
EVALUATE
ROW("TEST",FORMAT( 12345.678, "Currency") )
```

Would it be possible to have two decimal places and not round, like 12345.67 in money values?

Comment: read this resolved : https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/DAX-Query-Rounding/td-p/421747

Answer (score 0):

You can use the floor function in DAX:

```
FLOOR(<number>, <significance>)
```

So in your example:

```
EVALUATE
ROW("TEST",FORMAT( FLOOR(12345.678, 2), "Currency") )
```